# Avoid Loading Image dataset in Pycharm IDE multiple times(Load only once)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am working on an Image Classification problem using Keras/Tensorflow. The problem is that since I am using an IDE like Pycharm (I also use Jupyter Notebook), I am curious to know if there is any way where I can load the dataset from the directory only once and then when I re-run the whole `.py` file, I just use the images from already loaded data?

```
labels = ['rugby', 'soccer']
img_size = 224
def get_data(data_dir):
    data = [] 
    for label in labels: 
        path = os.path.join(data_dir, label)
        class_num = labels.index(label)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_arr = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img))[...,::-1] #convert BGR to RGB format
                resized_arr = cv2.resize(img_arr, (img_size, img_size)) # Reshaping images to preferred size
                data.append([resized_arr, class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
    return np.array(data)
Now we can easily fetch our train and validation data.


train = get_data('../input/traintestsports/Main/train')
val = get_data('../input/traintestsports/Main/test')
```

Every time get_data is called, it would require additional time to load entire datset

Comment: You should use a sequence data generator for an efficient input pipeline. I vote to close this question because it lacks more details. Please add more details of your problem to retract the close vote.

Answer (score 1):

You can read in each image using the [`cv2.imread()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) method, and use the [`np.save()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) method to save all the images *(put into a single array)* to save the data into a binary file in `.npy` format:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

imgs = ['image1.png', 'image2.png', 'image3.png', 'image4.png']

# Map each str to cv2.imread, convert map object to list, and convert list to array
arr = np.array(list(map(cv2.imread, imgs))) 

np.save('data.npy', arr)
```

When you want to access the data, you can use the [`np.load()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.load.html) method:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.load('data.npy')
```

You can install [`cv2`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html) *(OpenCV)* via the command prompt command:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

and [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/doc/) with

```
pip install numpy
```

---

If you have a more complex data type, you can use the [`pickle.dump()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump) method to save your data sterilized into a file:

```
import pickle

data = {"data": ['test', 1, 2, 3]} # Replace this with your dataset

with open("data.pickle", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f)
```

When you want to access the data, you can use the [`pickle.load()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.load) method:

```
import pickle

with open("data.pickle", "rb") as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)

print(data)
```

Output:

```
{'data': ['test', 1, 2, 3]}
```

The [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module is built into python.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. This is more like how to read and write the file in the system in python. Despite the unclear question, the OP mention about classification problem using tensorflow / keras - so the answer should be at least focusing on efficient data input pipelines with `tf. data` API or sequence data generator in keras.